# Is the professor allowed to force all of his students to retake the final

Tags: professorship

So my friends professor had his class take the final last week, but the problem was that the whole final was online even with all the answers, but he didn't find out till today and he is making everyone of his students retake it, and it got me wondering if that is legal and fair for the students who had already taken the final. My friend goes to Brooklyn College.

Comment: What do you mean by the final was online with all the answers? Was it posted before or after the exam? Who posted it?

Comment: I doubt there are any relevant laws here, but as long as school is still in session, and he's not scheduling anything outside of regularly scheduled class time, I don't see why not.

Comment: I can't comment on legality, but it strikes me as fair enough. It's unpleasant, but it's equally unpleasant for everyone.

Comment: It depends. If half your students have schedule conflicts and it's nearing the end of finals period: probably not.

Answer (score 6):

There's nothing illegal about it as far as I can see, so we can get that out of the way first.

As to fair, if there are still regularly scheduled class days, they can be used. If the exam is available online originally and planned to be made online again, then given a large enough testing window to account for other exams, I don't see a huge problem.

Now, if for whatever reason the exam would need to be retaken on campus or during a specific small window of time that students may have conflicts with, then the most logic solution in my mind is to make the final optional, or to cancel it all together.

However, the professor will have a fair amount of freedom to decide how to deal with the situation and will undoubtedly have consulted with their department head to make sure the solution seems reasonable (at my university we have to get our *dean* to approve any exam time outside the standard exam schedule). As a professor, I would personally consult with the department head if for no other reason then to give him a heads up on something that has the potential to generate academic grievances.

If your friend feels the solution is unjust, they should begin an academic grievance process, which will be outlined in the student handbook or similar. The first step is normally contacting the professor to discuss the issue.

Comment: Depending on the syllabus / assessment structure it may HAVE to take place... but good answer on all points.

Comment: @solarmike good point, if it's the primary source of the grade it may have to be done in some form or fashion to have a semi justifiable grade. I'll try to update my answer soon to integrate that possibility

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I interpret your question: someone posted the exam and the answers online, thus invalidating the exam.

I think that it is probably allowed, in this situation, to require a retake.  But if you want to be sure, check your university's policies.

I don't think the date matters.